# How to reference a JButton with an integer?

Tags: java, list, jbutton

Let's say we have 3 JButtons(or some other objects) :

```
JButton button1 = new JButton() , button2 = new JButton(), button3 = new JButton();
```

Now let's say that as a result of some function we have an integer from 1 to 3. Is it possible , for example, to decide what button to manipulate based on the given integer. So, if I came up with number 3, to select button3 like this :

```
button(3).setIcon(etc..);
```

Comment: Title says string, post says integer. Which do you need? Your code example screams array/list.

Comment: You need to store references to the buttons somewhere, e.g. in a `List` or `Map<Integer, JButton>`

Comment: Sounds like you want to put your buttons in an array.

Comment: How do you reference **any** collection of a certain type? Use an array or a collection

Comment: Just put your buttons into a List and grab them by the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider putting them in a `list` in the correct order... then you can do

`myList.get(0)`,`myList.get(1)` or `myList.get(2)` according to the insertion order

something like

```
List<JButton> myList = ....
myList.add(new JButton());
myList.add(new JButton());
myList.add(new JButton());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of `JButton` for your requirement with given size.

```
JButton buttons[]=new JButton[3];
for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)
   buttons[i]=new JButton();
```

Use In method

```
public void setIcon(int number){

   button[number].setIcon(etc..);
}
```

`ArrayList` is an option that provide dynamic arrays in Java, but if dynamic list is not your requirement use array also because `ArrayList` is slower than array.